# sqlite3_bind_text for variable number of values

Tags: c++, sqlite

I create a SQLite database with:

```
sqlite3 *db;
char *dbErrMsg;
int rc = sqlite3_open("test.dat", &db);
if (rc)
{
    std::cout << "cannot open database\n";
    exit(2);
}
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,
                  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS like ( userid, likeid );",
                  0, 0, &dbErrMsg);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,
                  "DELETE FROM like;",
                  0, 0, &dbErrMsg);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db,
                  "INSERT INTO like VALUES "
                  "(1,1),(1,2),"
                  "(2,2),(2,3),"
                  "(3,3),(3,1),"
                  "(4,3),(4,1);",
                  0, 0, &dbErrMsg);
```

Then run a SQL select from the command line tool

```
C:\Users\James\code\sharedLikes\bin>sqlite3 test.dat
SQLite version 3.36.0 2021-06-18 18:36:39
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT userid,likeid FROM like WHERE userid != 1 AND likeid IN (1,2);
2|2
3|1
4|1
```

All is working as expected.

Now I run the same select command using the C API

```
sqlite3_stmt *match;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,
                        "SELECT userid,likeid "
                        "FROM like "
                        "WHERE userid != 1 "
                        "AND likeid IN ( 1,2 );",
                        -1, &match, 0);
int found = 0;
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(match)) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    found++;
}
sqlite3_reset(match);
std::cout << found << " rows found\n";
```

Output is good:

```
3 rows found
```

But what I really want to do is run queries looking for a variable number of matching likes.  So I tried using `sqlite3_bind_text` like this

```
sqlite3_stmt *match2;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,
                        "SELECT userid,likeid "
                        "FROM like "
                        "WHERE userid != ?1 "
                        "AND likeid IN ( ?2 );",
                        -1, &match2, 0);
rc = sqlite3_bind_int( match2, 1, 1);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text( match2, 2, "1,2", -1,0);
found = 0;
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(match2)) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    found++;
}
sqlite3_reset(match2);
std::cout << found << " rows found\n";
```

Output shows that no rows are found

```
0 rows found
```

I used the debugger to check that rc was always returned as 0 ( no errors )  ( In the real code rc is checked, but I have removed the checks for readability in this test/demo. )

Here is the complete code for the demo application

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *dbErrMsg;
    int rc = sqlite3_open("test.dat", &db);
    if (rc)
    {
        std::cout << "cannot open database\n";
        exit(2);
    }
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db,
                      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS like ( userid, likeid );",
                      0, 0, &dbErrMsg);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db,
                      "DELETE FROM like;",
                      0, 0, &dbErrMsg);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db,
                      "INSERT INTO like VALUES "
                      "(1,1),(1,2),"
                      "(2,2),(2,3),"
                      "(3,3),(3,1),"
                      "(4,3),(4,1);",
                      0, 0, &dbErrMsg);

    sqlite3_stmt *match;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,
                            "SELECT userid,likeid "
                            "FROM like "
                            "WHERE userid != 1 "
                            "AND likeid IN ( 1,2 );",
                            -1, &match, 0);
    int found = 0;
    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(match)) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        found++;
    }
    sqlite3_reset(match);
    std::cout << found << " rows found\n";

    sqlite3_stmt *match2;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,
                            "SELECT userid,likeid "
                            "FROM like "
                            "WHERE userid != ?1 "
                            "AND likeid IN ( ?2 );",
                            -1, &match2, 0);
    rc = sqlite3_bind_int( match2, 1, 1);
    rc = sqlite3_bind_text( match2, 2, "1,2", -1,0);
    found = 0;
    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(match2)) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        found++;
    }
    sqlite3_reset(match2);
    std::cout << found << " rows found\n";
}
```

How can I run a SELECT ... IN ( ) query with a variable number of IN values?

---

Solution, following suggestion by @SHR:

```
int owner = 1;
std::string ownerInterests = "1,2";
std::string query = "SELECT userid,likeid "
                    "FROM like "
                    "WHERE userid != " +
                    std::to_string(owner) +
                    " AND likeid IN ( " + ownerInterests + " );";
std::cout << query << "\n";
sqlite3_stmt *match3;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(),
                        -1, &match3, 0);
found = 0;
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(match3)) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    found++;
}
sqlite3_reset(match3);
std::cout << found << " rows found\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind can be used to bind a single value. you can't bind several arguments in a single bind command.

your bind creates the following query: (with a single argument inside the IN condition)

```
SELECT userid,likeid FROM like WHERE userid != 1 AND likeid IN ( '1,2' )
```

you can append it to the query string (or use a `sprintf`...), but you must bind each argument in a single bind method. you can't create a list with a different count of elements in a single prepared statement.

You can create the query like this: (without binding, or bind only `userid`)

```
char sql_buffer[256]
sprintf (sql_buffer, "SELECT userid,likeid FROM like WHERE userid != 1 AND likeid IN ( %s )", 1,"1,2");
```

The binding must prevent SQL injection. what if you bind something with malicious code in an argument? for example: instead of `"1,2"`  I'll put `"1,2); delete from like where userid not in (-1"`, It allow a restricted user to delete your entire DB. you can't inject it when it is only a single argument.

Comment: Stated more succinctly:  sqlite3_bind_text cannot be used for this.  The query string must be manipulated using <string> functions, THEN passed into sqlite3_prepare_v2. See end of question